# Find number of pairs in the array such that all the elements between those pairs present in the array are smaller than the pairs itself

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers, optimization

We have an array of distinct positive integers. We have to find the number of pairs in the array such that all the elements between those pairs present in the array are smaller than the pair elements itself.

For e.g. if the array is [7 3 2 1 4 6 5] then the output would be 10, as all the integers between (7,4) , (7,6) , (3,4) , (2,4) in the array are smaller than the mentioned pairs and along with 6 adjacent pairs with no elements between them are taken into account, ie. (size(array) - 1), hence 4 + 6 = 10. Similarly for [10 3 4 8 6], the output would be 6 and for [2 80 4 32] the output would be 4.

I am able to achieve the results using brute force approach (2 nested loops) which is not efficient and also using stacks with concept of Next/Previous Greater element in O(N)(both time and space). However I am looking for a even more efficient or faster approach (maybe just using pointers, or manipulating the array beforehand) without using any extra DS/space i.e. O(N) time and O(1) space.

I have attached my code using stacks approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int n, pairs = 0;
   cin >> n;
   int arr[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    
    stack <int> s1, s2;
    
    int i = 1;
    s1.push(arr[0]);
    while (i < n) {
        if (!s1.empty() and arr[i] > s1.top()) {
            s1.pop();
            pairs++;
        }
        else {
            s1.push(arr[i]);
            i++;
        }
            
    }
    int j = n - 2;
    s2.push(arr[n-1]);
    while(j > -1) {
        if(!s2.empty() and arr[j] > s2.top()) {
            s2.pop();
            pairs++;
        }
        else {
            s2.push(arr[j]);
            j--;
        }
    }

    cout << pairs;
}
```

Comment: In your first example, why doesn't `(2, 4)` count but `(3,6)` does?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Have corrected it!

Comment: What do you mean by 'manipulating the array beforehand'? Unless you allow tricks like hiding information in the high bits of numbers, it seems unlikely that a linear time, constant auxiliary space solution would exist